# How to convert database rows into a byte array and back for a Saved Game snapshot using Google Play Games Services

Tags: java, android, arrays, google-play-games

The goal is to convert database rows into a Saved Game snapshot for Google Play Games Services, then retrieve those rows and insert them on a secondary device that would open the Saved Game snapshot.

I am able to save and retrieve snapshots to/from Google Play Games Service with basic string data, but how could I store database rows into a byte array (byte array is required to store snapshot data using Google Play Games Services) and back for a Saved Game snapshot? Thanks you.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong
Is your issue finding a way to represent a database record in memory as a byte[], and to retrieve back the database record from the byte[] ??

Comment: Correct, I'm looking for the best way to this. If there are any best practices or standard approaches to  doing this with minimal transformation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're asking for a way represent a database record in memory as a byte[].
If I was in your position, I would first do a simple modelling, by creating a java class which can represent the content of the data base record.

For example:

A database record: **{id, firstName, lastName}** I would simply create a java class as a model like this:

```
public class Contact {
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
// add getters and setters
}
```

Now when you do a database query and you have one or more records, you can create a new instance of this model for every record and set the content of the model instance from the records you have.

```
Contact contact = new Contact();
contact.setFirstName("The first name from the database record");
//And so on.
```

Now to convert a model instance into a byte[]

```
ByteArrayOutputStream arrOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(arrOutStream);
    out.writeObject(contact);
    byte[] bytes = arrOutStream.toByteArray();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And to read that object back from the byte[]

```
byte[] bytesToRead;
ByteArrayInputStream arrInStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesToRead);
try {
    ObjectInputStream objectInStream = new ObjectInputStream(arrInStream);
    contact = (Contact) objectInStream.readObject();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now since you have the model you can put it back into your database.

If you need to do this for multiple records from the database into a single byte[], you can simply create a new model that contains a list of contacts:

```
class Contacts {

    List<Contact> contactsList;
}
```

Instead of serializing every record into a byte[], you can just create one instance of the **Contacts** model, and add as much contacts inside, then do the serialization only once for the **Contacts** instance.

Comment: If I understand the above correctly, I would need to store each instance of the contact object into its own byte array. I'm limited to only a single byte array for saving a snapshot to Google Games Services, how could I store multiple database rows into a single byte array and back, thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at JSON serialization vs. object serialization.  Something like http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-serializing-collections/   The advantage is that the serialized bytes are smaller, and the deserialization is not tightly tied to the java classes used to read it.  This way, if you make a new model for your game, you don't need to keep serializable compatible versions of the old classes to read the player's old data.

Comment: @ClaytonWilkinson So something like this, should also be platform agnostic?: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types

Comment: Yes, there are JSON libraries for all the platforms.  For example if you send data to a backend server via REST, you can read the data  from PHP, Java, etc.

Comment: So in case of list of models the code should be :   out.writeObject(contactsList);  -- is it correct ?